# What's the difference between 好 and 完？

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

These two sentences should mean the same thing, so what exactly is the difference between them, and when should we use 好 VS 完？

我吃好了： I finished eating

我吃完了： I finished eating

Comment: searching site with ＂ 好 完 ＂yields
http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/9434/complement-of-result%e5%ae%8c-or-%e5%a5%bd/9435#9435

Comment: 我吃好了： I finished eating (with satisfaction).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[V + 完 ] simply means to **end**, to **complete** or to **finish** an action

[V + 好 ] means to **accomplish** an action, that imply the action itself is an **requirement**,

Example :

> '**Finish (complete)** eating then launch the attack'- '吃**完**了飯便出擊'
>
> *It simply describes the time line --  first, finish eating, then launch the attack*

~

> '**Finish (accomplish)** eating then launch the attack' - '吃**好**了飯便出擊'
>
> *Since the soldiers need strength to fight, 吃飯 would be an order (requirement) that needs to be accomplished,*

You can say 吃完飯再看電視 (finish eating, then watch tv.) but you cannot say 吃好飯再看電視 (accomplish eating, then watch tv.) if 'finishing eating' is not a requirement for watching TV.

[V + 好 ] can also means  [V + adequately]

Example:

> 做**完**準備 (**finish** the preparation)
>
> 做**好**準備 (**adequately** do the preparation/ **accomplish** the preparation)'
>
> 磨**完**刀 (**finish** sharpen the knife)
>
> 磨**好**刀 (**adequately** sharpen the knife / **accomplish** sharpen the knife)

Answer (score 0):

完：尽，无：用完了。煤烧完了。
   做成，了结：完毕。完成。完结。

好：完成，完善，完毕

完 只说明已经结束，用尽，完结。
好 带有一种褒义的，积极的，完善的完结含义，表示对完结的评估良好

例如：将军，我军的粮食已经吃完了！

这儿完，就不能用好代替，因为这儿是负面情绪